# Reducing likelihood of PDF export error in Google Apps Script with Sheets

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using GAS to export several sheets of a Google spreadsheet to PDFs. Occasionally, the PDF exports a file with the following message:

> This file might be unavailable right now due to heavy traffic.

[image: PDF export error]

I've tried using sleep() between exports to slow down the processing, but I still get the error on a number of the PDFs. Luckily they are relatively easy to spot because they are always 15kb in size, but I'd like to find a solution rather than a workaround.

```
function updateModules() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var template = ss.getSheetByName("-Template");
  var questionTemplate = template.getRange(4,2,1,5);
  var urlOptions = {muteHttpExceptions: true};

  // make array of concept names
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('-ACT English Answers').getRange(2,6,2000).getValues();
  concepts = [];
  concepts.push(data[0]);
  var m = 0;
  while (m < data.length) {
    if (concepts.join().indexOf(data[m].join()) == -1) {
        concepts.push(data[m]);
    };
    m++;
  }
  concepts.sort();

  // loop through questions per sheet
  var n = 0;
  while (n < concepts.length) {
    
    // Use for individual sheets with errors.
    //concepts = [['Dashes'],['Usage'],['Main ideas'],['Independent/Dependent clauses']];

    var name = concepts[n][0];

    // make sheet with formatting and copy template for any new concepts
    if (!ss.getSheetByName(name)) {
      ss.insertSheet(name);
      Logger.log("New sheet: " + name)
    }

    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var sheetDestination = sheet.getRange(1,1,4,6);
    var testCodeRange = sheet.getRange('A1:A');
    var copyTemplate = template.getRange(1,1,4,6);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var columnBWidth = template.getColumnWidth(2);
    var columnCWidth = template.getColumnWidth(3);
    var columnEWidth = template.getColumnWidth(5);

  // reset sheet, copy top 4 rows of template with column widths, set concept name in A1
    sheet.getRange('A5:J').clear();
    sheet.showColumns(1);
    sheet.unhideRow(testCodeRange);
    testCodeRange.setFontSize(9);
    copyTemplate.copyTo(sheetDestination);
    copyTemplate.copyTo(sheetDestination,SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS,false);
    sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(name);
    sheet.setRowHeight(3,77);
    sheet.setHiddenGridlines(true);
    sheet.getRange('A4:F').setBorder(false,false,false,false,false,true,"black",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);

    Logger.log(name);
    
    // iterate through each concept's question codes
    var values = testCodeRange.getValues(); // get all data in one call
    var row = 4; // A4 contains FILTER(), which lists question codes for given concept
    while ( values[row-1] && values[row-1][0] != "" ) {
      
      // get image dimensions
      var question = values[row-1][0];
      var passageUrl = "https://www.openpathtutoring.com/static/img/concepts/language/passages/" + question + ".jpg";
      var questionUrl = "https://www.openpathtutoring.com/static/img/concepts/language/questions/" + question + ".jpg";
      var passageImg = UrlFetchApp.fetch(passageUrl, urlOptions);
      var questionImg = UrlFetchApp.fetch(questionUrl, urlOptions);
      var passageBlob = passageImg.getBlob();
      var questionBlob = questionImg.getBlob();
      var passageSize = ImgApp.getSize(passageBlob);
      var questionSize = ImgApp.getSize(questionBlob);
      var questionHeight = questionSize.height / questionSize.width * columnEWidth + 20;
      

      // for 2-column images, set passage height based on 2-column width; merge cells
      if (passageSize.width > 1111) {
        var passageHeight = passageSize.height / passageSize.width * (columnBWidth + columnCWidth) + 20;
      }
      else {
        passageHeight = passageSize.height / passageSize.width * columnBWidth + 20;
      }

      // set rowHeight to the greater of passageHeight and questionHeight   
      if (passageHeight >= questionHeight) {
        var rowHeight = passageHeight;
      }
      else {
        var rowHeight = questionHeight;
      };

      // set rowHeight, copy image formulas from template, merge cells if needed
      sheet.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
      questionTemplate.copyTo(sheet.getRange(row,2,1,5));

      if (passageSize.width > 1111) {
        sheet.getRange(row,2,1,2).mergeAcross();
      }

      row++;
    }

    // unhide relevant rows; hide column A+F and gridlines; set horizontal borders
    //sheet.hideRows(2,sheet.getMaxRows()-1);
    sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange(row,1,sheet.getMaxRows()-row+1));
    sheet.hideColumns(1)
    sheet.hideColumns(6);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    //* save worksheets
    savePdf(ss, name, "_" + name, "1qZHgCGCDjkbKwPOTHxo4sg1YuWtYxQva", 0.25);
    Utilities.sleep(3000);
    //*/

    // show answer key after exporting PDFs
    sheet.showColumns(1);
    sheet.showColumns(6);
    sheet.getRange('A1:A').setVerticalAlignment("middle");
    //sheet.getRange('F1:F').setVerticalAlignment("middle").setHorizontalAlignment('center');

    //* Create answer keys
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    savePdf(ss, name, "_" + name + " (Answers)", "1rdzP-okNaqG7d_03aBV3GNngjHeLARdO", 2.2);
    Utilities.sleep(3000);
    //*/
    n++;
  }

  sortSheets();
}

function savePdf(spreadsheetId, sheetName, pdfName, pdfFolderId, bottomMargin) {
  
  var sheetId = spreadsheetId.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId();
  var url_base = spreadsheetId.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
  + '&gid=' + sheetId
  // following parameters are optional...
  + '&size=A4'      // paper size: legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&top_margin=0.25'
  + '&bottom_margin=' + bottomMargin
  + '&left_margin=0.375'
  + '&right_margin=0.375'
  + '&sheetnames=false' // 
  + '&printtitle=false'
  + '&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
  + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
  + '&fzr=false';       // false = do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  var url_options = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),},muteHttpExceptions: true};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, url_options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(pdfFolderId);
  folder.createFile(blob);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the script for the function `savePdf`?

Comment: @IrvinJayG. apologies for the delay. I've added `savePdf` at the bottom of the code block.